# Display different text on page depending on number of published posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to display different text when there are three posts in selected category and different when I add more posts...
Something like "if number of posts >= 3 show TEXT1 else TEXT2".
This does not work:

```
<?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'upoutavka','category__in' => '12, 13',); 
$postslist = get_posts( $args ); 
if(count($posts) >= 3)
{
  echo "TEXT2";
}
else
{ 
  echo "TEXT1"
}
?>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'upoutavka', // Change this to any custom post type.
    'posts_per_page' => -1,          // Show all posts.
    'fields'         => 'ids',       // Return only post id we don't need all post data for post count.
    'category__in'   => array( 3 )   // Change this to current category id.
);

$posts = get_posts( $args );

if ( count( $posts ) >= 3 ) {
    echo __( 'Text no. 2', 'text-domain' );
} else {
    echo __( 'Text no. 1', 'text-domain' );
}
```

Comment: Thank you! When I added also count( $posts ) <= 2 it works!